# How to mod rewrite with dashes in variables

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My current url is:

```
/mod.php?name=gal&file=cati&cat=8&caturl=animals-nature&gurl=photo-gallery&offset=1
```

I want to make it:

```
animals-nature-photo-gallery-8p1.html
```

My current .htaccess

```
 RewriteRule ^([^/#$%(){}.&-]+)-([^/#$%(){}.&]+)-([1-9][0-9]*)p([1-9][0-9]*).html mod.php?name=gal&file=cati&cat=$3&caturl=$1&gurl=$2&offset=$4 [L]
```

I get correctly rewrited url, but in query string $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] result is:

```
 /mod.php?name=gal&file=cati&cat=8&caturl=**animals**&gurl=**nature-photo-gallery**&offset=1
```

So $_GET variable for caturl = animals which is false!

Please help to fix it.

Comment: The problem here is to distinguish the beginning and the end of a part of your url. For instance, how could `mod-rewrite` knows if it has to match `animals` or `animals-nature` or `animals-nature-photo` etc.. ? I mean, do you have a fixed pattern such that you can know if `caturl` (for instance) must contain only one dash ?

Comment: why is "it" not a full URL? It makes it hard to understand your desire here.

Answer (score 0):

If `caturl` always has exactly one hyphen and `gurl` has exactly one hyphen too, you can check for with a [non-greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) expression

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?-.+?)-(.+?-.+?)-([1-9][0-9]*)p([1-9][0-9]*).html mod.php?name=gal&file=cati&cat=$3&caturl=$1&gurl=$2&offset=$4 [L]
```